# Why does this method lead to concurrency issues?

Tags: java, multithreading

I synchronize the code below, but it leads to concurrency issues.

I know this is caused by multi-thread, I was confused by the `synchronized` keyword. I expected a `list.length` value of 100. How can I fix it?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class ThreadA extends Thread {

    private static byte[] lock = new byte[0];

    private static final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void run() {

        System.out.println(list.size());

        synchronized(lock) {
            int size = list.size();
            if( size == 0 ) return;

            if(size >= 100) {
                list.clear();
            }
        }

    }

    public void add(String s) {
        list.add(s);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            new ThreadA().start();
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    synchronized(lock) {
                        for(int m = 0; m < 100; m++) {
                            list.add(new Date().toLocaleString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }

        System.out.println("LIST.SIZE:" + list.size());
    }

}
```

Comment: Is this your homework for today?

Comment: Shouldn't your first run() method execute a loop? It finishes really fast the way it is.

Comment: Try adding this line right before the final print of LIST.SIZE: Thread.sleep(4000);  That should at least give you a handle on part of what's going wrong.

Comment: Why did you expect the size to be 100, rather than 0?

Comment: No, i treats two different method as two block, and first block clears all elements of list.length >= 100, and second adds 100 elements once.
i dont wish it was cleared, when sencond had add 50 elements..
they are seperate part..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

1. The println accesses `list` without synchronization and without waiting for the threads to complete. You'll get whatever the value of list was at that moment.
2. There is no guarantee in what order the threads will execute. It could happen that the all the `ThreadA` instances run before the anonymous threads and the result could be a value significantly more than 100.

Comment: If an answer appeared to be useful, please upvote it (press ^ button).